# How can I get all established http-connections on my express.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, server-sent-events

I`m using SSE (server send events) on my express server app to notify clients with some events. Code on my server:

```
sseRouter.get("/stream", (req, res) => {
   sse.init(req, res);
 });

let streamCount = 0;  

class SSE extends EventEmitter {    
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.connections = [];
  }

  init(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      Connection: "keep-alive",
      "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    });
    console.log("client connected init...");
    this.connections.push(req);  //?  

    let id = 0;
    res.write(`data: some data \n\n`);
   
    const dataListener = (data) => {
      
      if (data.event) {
        res.write(`event: ${data.event} \n`);
      }
      res.write(`event: ${data.data} \n`);
      res.write(`id: ${++id} \n`);
      res.write("\n");
    };

    this.on("data", dataListener);

    req.on("close", () => {
      this.removeListener("data", dataListener);
      
      --streamCount;
      console.log("Stream closed");
    });        
}};
```

Using this code I can only count total amount of connections by incrementing "streamCount" variable, but i also need to save each established http-connection from client:

```
>  eventSource = new EventSource(`${Constants.DEV_URL}/stream`);
```

to some array or set collections to manage this connections but i can not understand how to extract every unique established connection on server.

Answer (score 1):

I think it as simple as changing `this.connections.push(req);` into:

```
this.connections.push(res);
```

I.e. the `res`ponse handle can be used at any time to `write()` more data. So to later send the same `msg` to everyone you can do:

```
const msg = new Date().toISOString()
for(const res of this.connections)await res.write(`data:${msg}\n\n`);
```

You will also need a way to remove their entry when they disconnect, or you get a write error, so `this.connections` as a simple array may not be the best data structure.